# After F5 it loads indefinitely

Tags: bug, firefox

When I press F5 in Firefox 24.3.0 (for Linux) while browsing [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696652/a-relation-between-certain-families-of-filters-and-filters-on-a-cartesian-produc), the rotating circle indicating loading of the page continues to rotate for an extended period of time.

When I just open URL, it opens quickly and it stops to rotate.

It seems that in some reason F5 reloads are handled wrongly.

Comment: Are you sure your keyboard isn't stuck?

Comment: I am sure my keyboard isn't stuck

Comment: Note that this bug doesn't happen with http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12906/after-f5-it-loads-indefinitely page

Comment: Your post seems to indicate that this is browser specific, so I have added ([meta-tag:firefox]) tag. If you experience the same problem in other browsers too, please, remove this tag (and mention this fact in your post.)

Comment: This works fine for me: up-to-date Arch Linux, Firefox v30.0a1.

Comment: Now the bug disappeared. I can't reproduce it